# Printing strings with a GUI

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I'm practicing at home to get better in my computer science class and I'm having trouble with a certain code I am trying to make. The code pasted below is supposed to print one of the five options found in "public static void associate()" in the "Joketeller" class. However, when I run my GUI and click the button to test it, the text box where the response is supposed to appear in does not do anything.

```
public class GUIWindow extends JFrame {
private Joketeller robot= new Joketeller();
private JLabel speakerlabel = new JLabel("Joke");
private JLabel MarcoLabel= new JLabel ("Marco");
private JTextField speakerfield= new JTextField ("Enter Joke Here");
private JTextField Marcofield= new JTextField ("");
private JButton Jokebutton=new JButton("Recite Joke >>>");

public GUIWindow()  {
    JPanel dataPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,12,16));
    dataPanel.add(speakerlabel);
    dataPanel.add(MarcoLabel);
    dataPanel.add(speakerfield);
    dataPanel.add(Marcofield);

    JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(Jokebutton);
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.add(dataPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Jokebutton.addActionListener(new JokeListener());
}

    private class JokeListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input=speakerfield.getText();
        robot.setJoke(input);
        String Response= Joketeller.getResponse();
        Marcofield.setText(Response);


        }
        }
    }
```

And here's my Joketeller class:

```
public class Joketeller {


    private static String Marco;
    private static String Response;
    static int i= (int)(Math.random()*((5-1)+1))+1;
    static String r;

    public void setMarco(String Joke ) {
        Marco=Joke;
    }

    public void setJoke(String Joke) {
        Marco=Joke;
    }


    public String getJoke() {
        return Marco;
    }

    public static String getMarco() {
        return Marco;
    }

        public static void associate(){
        if(i==1) 
            r= "Connect Angie";
        else if(i==2)
            r= "*Cloud Laugh*";
        else if(i==3)
            r= "Community";
        else if(i==4)
            r=getMarco();
        else if(i==5)
            r= "Indeed!";
        Response=r;

        }

    public static String getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you are not assigning input field to Response, either assign it to response or return Macro

Answer (score 1):

please check the following link:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/30textfield/11textfield.html

also Basically you should do

JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(16);

Where myOutput is what you choose the JTextField's variable to be and 16 is the length of the JTextField in the GUI. To display a message:

myOutput.setText("some text");
You can also initialize the value of the JTextField while declaring the text field at the same time

JTextField myOutput = new JTextField("someInitialValue", 20);
The code speaks for itself

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to a hook in associate() execution somewhere, for instance when `robot.setJoke(input);`  is invokes.

Modify `Joketeller` class as follows and output shall come.

```
public void setJoke(String Joke) {
        associate();
        Marco=Joke;
    }
```